# Trying to compile my app with Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt, qml

Here is the bottom part of the compile output. I am stuck, please help. I can't seem to find anything regarding error 15. Also, when I compile and this error shows a .apk seems to still be created, but when I post to Google Play as an internal test the app crashes instantly and the icon has no name under it. I'm not very experienced with this program/code but I've gotten it to this point. Need some expert advice please.

```
23132854 res/layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml (OK - compressed)
23133325 res/layout/splash.xml (OK - compressed)
23133595 res/layout/support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml (OK - compressed)
23133952 resources.arsc (OK)
Verification succesful
Signed
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Number of signers: 1
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_animated-vector-drawable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_appcompat-v7.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_cardview-v7.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_customtabs.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-vector-drawable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths:      QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
23:37:05: The process "C:\V-PlaySDK\V-Play\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 15.
Error while building/deploying project Project_Name (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.10.1 Android armv7 V-Play))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
23:37:05: Elapsed time: 00:38.
```

Comment: See if you can pass the `--verbose` argument to `androiddeployqt` somehow.

Comment: I checked off the -verbose argument in the kit details, not sure why it isn't showing more info on the error.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source of `androiddeployqt`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/tools/androiddeployqt/main.cpp#n2758), an exit code of `15` is `CannotSignPackage`, so something goes wrong with signing. In addition, it could be that the META-INF warnings are related to this.

Comment: If I take signing off it does not give me an error but builds a debug .apk even though I am building it in release mode. It looks like Google Play may take care of signing now but it won't accept a debug build, sorry I'm just learning on the fly right now lol.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately, I have very little experience with the process, so I can't offer more help.

Comment: Well thank you for trying, I do appreciate it. How did you determine error 15 is CannotSignPackage? Just trying to learn where to find these things.

Comment: See the page I linked to. :)

Comment: Ah, found it. Thank you so much.

Comment: What a pain, it needs to be signed to build in release mode, but signing is what's stopping it from building properly. I've tried different keys, made with qt creator and android studio. No luck. Really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try posting on the interest mailing list: http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/interest